# Prove or disprove: $e^{-nG(x)}$, normalized, is an approximation to the identity for $G(x)$ strictly convex

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution, dirac-delta

We are given the sequence of functions
$$ \phi_{n} = \frac{e^{-nG(x)}}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-nG(x)}dx}$$
for a nonnegative, strictly convex function $G$ (that is, $G'' \geq c$ for some $c>0$) that attains its global minimum at 0.
It is clear that $\phi_{n} \geq 0$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_{n}=1$ for each $n$. For the $\phi_{n}$ to be considered an approximation to the convolutive identity (that is, they approximate a dirac delta function), we require that for each $\delta>0$ and $\epsilon>0$,
there exists an $N$ large enough that
$$ \int_{|x|>\delta}\phi_{n} < \epsilon$$
for each $n>N$.

Is it true that the $\phi_{n}$ satisfy this last property for $G$ as specified? I suspect it is true, due to known examples like $x^{2}$.

If true, can we loosen the conditions on $G$ to include other known functions like $|x|$? Perhaps a sufficient condition is that $G$ attains its global minimum exactly once, is strictly decreasing to the left of that minimum, and strictly increasing to the right of it.

Comment: First off, it should be clear that this can't happen if the global minimum is attained somewhere other than 0, because these functions will be concentrating around the global minimum of $G$, whereas the Dirac delta is concentrated at 0. With that aside, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method should help you.

Comment: The condition proposed at the end needs more: $e^{-nG}$ might not even be integrable with only those assumptions.  (E.g., $G(x)=|x|/(|x|+1)$.)

Comment: Thank you Ian, I've updated the question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be convex and with minimum at zero — and only at zero.

(We don't need $G$ to be nonnegative, nor do we need it to be strictly convex.  Note that our assumptions allow $G(x)=|x|$, as requested at the end of the question.  In fact, the idea of this proof is essentially to use convexity to relate $G$ to a function made up of two straight lines, like $|x|$, and to prove it for such functions directly.)

Let $\delta>0$.  We wish to show $\int_\delta^\infty \phi_n(x)\,dx \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, and the same for $\int_{-\infty}^{-\delta}$.  I'll do the first; the second is similar.  Consider the secant of the graph of $G$ over $[0,\delta]$:

[image: A convex function and a secant of its graph]

The secant is $y=a+bx$, where $a=G(0)$ and $b=(G(\delta)-G(0))/\delta$.  (Note that $b>0$ because $G(0)$ is the only minimum of $G$.)  As the diagram suggests, since $G$ is convex,
\begin{align*}
G(x) &\le a+bx &&\text{if $0\le x\le\delta$,}\\
G(x) &\ge a+bx &&\text{if $\delta\le x$.}
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\int_\delta^\infty e^{-nG(x)}\,dx
\le \int_\delta^\infty e^{-n(a+bx)}\,dx
= e^{-na} \int_\delta^\infty e^{-nbx}\,dx
= \frac{e^{-na}}{nb} \int_{\delta bn}^\infty e^{-u}\,du
\end{align*}
(where the substitution $u=nbx$ is legitimate because $b\ne 0$), and
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-nG(x)}\,dx
\ge \int_0^\delta e^{-nG(x)}\,dx
\ge \int_0^\delta e^{-n(a+bx)}\,dx
= \frac{e^{-na}}{nb} \int_0^{\delta bn} e^{-u}\,du
\end{align*}
Dividing,
$$ \int_\delta^\infty \phi_n(x)\,dx
= \frac{\int_\delta^\infty e^{-nG(x)}\,dx}
  {\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-nG(x)}\,dx}
\le \frac{\int_{\delta bn}^\infty e^{-u}\,du}
  {\int_0^{\delta bn} e^{-u}\,du}
\to 0 \qquad\text{as $n\to\infty$.}
$$
(We used $b>0$ again at the end there, to make sure that $\delta bn$ increases with $n$.)